# Create list/array from a dictionary using custom function

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, transformation

I've such an input array that every element of the array is a dictionary `{x:a_int, y:a_int}`. Now I need to extract all `y` values and create a new array, so that it can be used to calculate the maximum of all `y`-values. Here is my current code:

```
var inputArray = [{x:1,y:100},{x:2,y:101},{x:3,y:103}];

function extractY(data) {
    var result = [];
    data.forEach(function (item) {
      result.push(item.y);
    });
    return result;
}

// Test code
var yArray = extractY(inputArray);
console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, yArray));
```

I want to make code shorter. As I'm new to javascript, I'd like to know, if it possible to shorten the function `extractY()`. My imagination is to have a transformation function. The code should not rely on `jQuery` and does not have to consider old browser compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which will create a new Array with the values returned by the function passed to it, like this

```
function extractY(data) {
    return data.map(function (item) {
      return item.y;
    });
}
```

Or you can simply write the same as

```
console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, inputArray.map(function(item) {
    return item.y;
})));
```

Comment: Your answer is educational. Yepp, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Very impressive.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), you can get the maximum y value directly:

```
inputArray.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.y > curr.y ? prev : curr;
}).y
```

Comment: Good to know such a nice skill.

Answer (score 1):

With underscore:

```
_.max(_.pick(inputArray, 'y'))
```

With d3:

```
d3.max(inputArray, function(d) { return d.y; })
```

Note in response to @AmitJoki's comment: Yes, I know this question was not tagged underscore. If you don't want to use underscore, feel free to ignore this answer. Having said that, underscore is a highly useful utility toolbelt that is perfect for solving problems such as this, among many other things. It's exhaustively tested and robust and efficient and handles all the edge cases correctly. Unlike certain other bloated libraries, it's quite lightweight and is well worth learning.

I doubt if it falls within the realm of common sense to imply that the failure to mark a question "underscore" means that underscore-based answers are somehow not acceptable, considering that it's easy to imagine that in many cases the OP may not even be aware of that option and might welcome a suggestion about how to write more compact code, while learning a useful tool in the process.

Comment: there's no underscore tagged

Comment: Wow! Currently my chart page uses `d3` and `rickshaw`. I'd digg deeper to see, if `d3` also has a similar helper function.